# Why is there a open bar below my images between the border/outline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out why there is an open space between my image and the border/outline. I've set all of the borders, margins, and paddings to 0. I've even tried to take away any possible overflow, but it still remains. I looked to try to solve it using chrome's developer tools, but I had no success. I would love it if you guys could take a look and try to figure out what is happening. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
  

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
}

.column img:hover {
  background-color:black;
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  top:160px;
  left:20px;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  border: 0.5rem outset pink;
  outline: 0.5rem solid khaki;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:50px;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:300px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:300px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:200px;
  top:80px;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:700px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:700px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  border: 0.5rem outset pink;
  outline: 0.5rem solid khaki;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:700px;
    padding-bottom:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:700px;
    margin-bottom:500px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  border: 0.5rem outset pink;
  outline: 0.5rem solid khaki;
  overflow:none;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.jpeg"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/1200x0/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5e7b54939f46de0006e48f1c%2F0x0.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'> Parapraph #6 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<p>` tags have a margin bottom of `1em`, add a `margin-bottom: 0;` to the `.head` class in your CSS and hopefully it'll dissappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the image is an inline element and hence behaves like text. You can get rid of this effect by making the `<img>` tag use `display: block` or by setting `font-size: 0` or `line-height: 0` on the `<div>`.